# Why do I get different answers when using $u$ substitution versus when I do not

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DIGeneralRegion.aspx
Example $1$, problem (c):

> $\int \int (6x^2 -40y)\, dA$, of triangle $A$ having vertices $(0,3), (5,3)$ and $(1,1)$.

On the “$-20(3-2x)^2$” section of the D$1$ integral (the left one), why does distributing that out result in a different answer than using $u=3-2x$, and $-0.5\, du= 1$, to make that section be $$-\dfrac{10}3(3-2x)^3$$ 
I finished integration through distributing the section and got a different result than the picture did, because the picture used $u$ substitution. They also used $u$ substitution in the same manner in the D$2$ integral of the problem, and I once again got a different answer by distributing instead of using $u$ substitution.

Comment: These bits and pieces of your calculations don't show the place where you are making your mistakes. You'll have to post your full calculations for us to see that. There are many errors that you could be making. For example I do not see where you are getting "$-0.5\, du= 1$" from. $u$ substitution does not give you a constant integrand.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think there are a lot of things you want to double check in your computations.

First, in the exercise the expression they have is $+20(3-2x)^2$.

Second, I think you mean $-\frac{1}{2} du = dx$.

Third, with that substitution you find
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 20(3-2x)^2 dx = - \int_3^1 10 u^2 du = - \frac{10}{3} \left. u^3\right\vert_{3}^{1} = - \frac{10}{3}+90 = \frac{260}{3} \ .
\end{equation}

This is the same result that you find by expanding and integrating directly 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 20(3-2x)^2 dx = \int_0^1 ( 80 x^2 - 240 x +180 ) dx = \frac{80}{3}-120+180 = \frac{260}{3} \ .
\end{equation}